# Geolocation with wordpressmu/buddypress

Tags: geolocation, wordpress, buddypress

I am just looking for the best solution for the following problem.
I have installed wordpress mu, and I wanted to create child blogs, for different areas in the world. But I want it so 1 domain can switch them instantly using the users ip address.

IS there a extention of wordpressmu or buddypress or do I need something on the server say in htaccess to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin out: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ip-to-country/

You could possibly use this, check the value returned, and set a WordPress cookie for the user that automatically redirects them to the geo-specific blog and will do so if/when they return to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Google API for geocoding, user detection, and geogrouping options (redirect all users from combined location like 'Europe'). Rather then doing all the heavy lifting on your server, work with the Google API, get your nicely formatted answer back, and redirect based on that....

Anything that involves geographical relation .... GOOGLE GOOGLE GOOLE